# Splitting point shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile with few points, I would like to export in separately shapefiles for each point.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and the split tool in ArcToolBox only works for polygons, but not for points.

Any help?